# SH_DENY* equivalent in Solaris

Tags: c++, gcc, porting

Solaris equivalent to fcntl.h and share.h

I am porting a big C++ project from `Windows/VS to Solaris/Eclipse/gcc`. The Windows code uses `_SH_DENYNO` etc which are in a Microsoft file share.h. The same file on the Sun at `/usr/include/sys` does not contain these, nor does any other I can find.

I suppose they have another name in Solaris. Can someone tell me where to find their equivalent? The windows versions have these values:

```
 #define _SH_DENYRW      0x10    /* deny read/write mode */
 #define _SH_DENYWR      0x20    /* deny write mode */
 #define _SH_DENYRD      0x30    /* deny read mode */
 #define _SH_DENYNO      0x40    /* deny none mode */
 #define _SH_SECURE      0x80    /* secure mode */
```

Do the Solaris versions have the same values?

(Sorry about the big font, it insisted)

Comment: What makes you think there are Solaris versions?

Comment: If you explain what they are for, you may get suggestions from people knowing Solaris and not Windows, the way you phrase your question, only people knowing both may answer.

Comment: >only people knowing both may answer

Well spotted, that is exactly what I was hoping for. They are flags used when opening files in shared mode.

>What makes you think there are Solaris versions

Well, the windows stuff doesn't compile, so I hope someone can help me. If I knew what I was doing I wouldn't have to ask...
Indeed someone did give me a useful answer, see below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think solaris, like other unix, is always `_SH_DENYNO`. You need explicit locking of files, try `lockf` or `fcntl`.